# Should return a single column value if any the whole column value are not same in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+------+
|Status|
+------+
|2     |
+------+
|1     |
+------+
|2     |
+------+
|2     |
+------+
|2     |
+------+
```

In this table the Column named status has one different value which is 1 so it should return me a single column status with one value PENDING else if all the status value are 2 then it should return single column status with one value COMPLETED

Output should look like this

```
 +------+
|Status |
+------ +
|Pending|
+-------+
```

Comment: can you add those tables with formatting?

Comment: Do you have to do this with only `SQL` ?

Comment: Yes in MYSQL i have to do

Comment: Do you have only 1 & 2s in the table?

Comment: i have 0 and 3 also in table

Answer (score 2):

Check the number of different status (1 excluded) to be not greater then 0:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'PENDING' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END AS 'Status' FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT status FROM yourtable WHERE status != 1
) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >1 THEN 'PENDING' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END  FROM
(
 SELECT Status FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY Status
)Z
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given that the only two possible values in your data set are 1 & 2, you can run the following query to get the result you want.

Note: I assume here that 2s are for completed values and 1s are for pending values. Therefore the sum of all rows should be equal to 'no. of rows' x 2 if all are completed. Otherwise it means there's a non matching value (which is 1)

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN count(status) * 2 = SUM(status) THEN 'COMPLETED'
        ELSE 'PENDING'
    END AS status
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess below query might help you:-

```
select 
CASE WHEN count(*) = 0 then 'COMPLETED'
ELSE 'PENDING' END
from testing where status in ('1');
```

Comment: If there is record with status `3,4,5,..` your query won't worked.

Comment: Agree with your point.
But we can modify the query with our requirements.

Comment: @VivekSharma if I have multiple status code and the result should be completed if all value is 2 so?